# Pathfinding using Bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, path-finding

Where could I find a good as3 class for Pathfinding, using a bitmap?

The white pixels would be traversable and the not white would be obstacles.

So I could find a node, say, at point (34, 33), (starting point), and make a path (setting pixels colors) to the point (300, 240),(ending point).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also call getVector() on the BitmapData to extract the pixel information ([see link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getVector%28%29)). You just need to find a library for ASTAR that uses an input vector with values of 0 being blocked. If one doesn't exist, it should be fairly easy to update a existing library like http://www.dauntless.be/astar/ to use uint Vector grids.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt such a specialized class exists, so you would probably have to write it yourself. A* (A-star) is quite simple to implement, and should work fine for this case.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star

If performance is not an issue (it will not be done very often), you can probably get away with the even simpler Dijkstra's algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm